# how to create the game doll/bomb in memory?

Tags: c, ide, 8051

I'm doing a game on a LCD. The game is about a doll thaht apears de right side of LCD and it could be controled by the user. On the left side a "bomb" apears randomly. The user have to deflect the doll from the bomb.
The program is programmed is C with MUC 8051 IDE.
The Professor suggested build intire game in memory (with an array) and then send everything for LCD.
I need help to start and to build the algorithm of the bomb shoot.

Answer (score 2):

Have an array of X*Y units, where X and Y are the dimensions of your LCD, and units is bits or characters depending on the type of your LCD (graphical or character-based).

Then you can change everything inside the array whenever you want, and when you want to update the screen you just write the complete array.